# Correct Steps for a Java Gui related project

Tags: java, swing, project

I am developing a plagiarism detection framework using Java. For that we have to come up with a GUI to take user inputs and process them. So we have to develop application logic as well. I want to know in general what is the correct steps of developing these kind of applications. 
Whether I should create the GUI first and then go to develop the logic or the otherway.
It will be helpful if someone can post me a link related to creating a custom GUI using Java Swing with a professional look.

Comment: Hire someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: Just find a nice public domain program and copy the good parts for your program.  Wait... wouldn't that be somewhat ironic?

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle Swing tutorials are a great resource for building Swing apps.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html

I would suggest doing a little of both at the same time.  After you have the basic GUI and logic working you can do some rough testing and make any major changes that are needed.  Once the logic and GUI framework appear to meeting your requirements you can go back and make the GUI look "Pretty".

Tips for more professional looking apps:

- Learn and use LayoutManagers for layout your components out.
- Learn and use SwingWorker in order to keep your GUI from hanging while it is processing
- Make use of an alternative look and feel like Nimbus.  (In my opinion using Nimbus can have a big effect with little code)

Comment: This is the kind of task that sounds as though it might profitably be attempted using tools that have no rich client GUI.  E.G. an ant task or servlet.  For that reason alone I would be cautious of developing the GUI alongside the logic, instead sticking primarily to non-GUI development for most of the early parts of the project.  (And speaking as someone who loves to wrap a GUI around any logic ASAP, I realize how painful it can be to develop apps. with no GUI.)  Of course, if the OP is **certain** this will only ever be a rich client, it makes my point moot.

Comment: @Andrew, good points.  I was recommending both mostly in the case because the GUI seems like such a major focus of the project.  If he has never built one before it would be useful to at least start on it so he has a rough idea of the effort involved.